# SQL: How to insert data into a table with column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

When inserting data into a SQL Server table, is it possible to specify which column you want to insert data to?

For a table with

I know you can have syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, col4_on, col8_on, col9_on)
VALUES ('myName', 0, 1, 0)
```

But the above syntax becomes unwieldy when you have lots of columns, especially if they have binary data. It becomes hard to match up which 1 and 0 go with which column.  I'm hoping there's a named-parameter like syntax (similar to what C# has) which looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
VALUES (Name: 'myName', col4_on: 0, col8_on: 1, col9_on: 0)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the first one is the only way to do this. What's the difference between having to type in the column names in scenario 1 and scenario 2? Same amount of work in my opinion. Also, you don't even need column names.

Comment: IF you have that many columns that this is a problem it might be a db design issue.Just keep the column names in a txt,copy-paste.

Comment: @PaulG What's the difference between labeling the folders in a filing cabinet vs sticking all the labels to the top of the cabinet in the same order as the folders?  Same amount of work.  Also, you don't even need the labels. (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way around this but it's rather hacky and only works for tables which has columns with unique values:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES ('myName')
UPDATE MyTable
SET col4_on=0, col8_on=1, col9_on=0
WHERE Name = 'myName'
```

This could be expanded into a multiple row insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES ('row1'), ('row2'), ('row3')
UPDATE MyTable SET col4_on=0, col8_on=1, col9_on=0 WHERE Name = 'row1'
UPDATE MyTable SET col4_on=1, col8_on=0, col9_on=0 WHERE Name = 'row2'
UPDATE MyTable SET col4_on=1, col8_on=1, col9_on=1 WHERE Name = 'row3'
```

Answer (score 8):

You must specify the column names.  However, there is one exception.  If you INSERTing *exactly* the same number of columns as the target table has *in the same order* as they are in the table, use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES ('val1A', 'val4A', 'val8A')
```

Note that this is a fragile way of performing an `INSERT`, because if that table changes, or if the columns are ordered differently on a different system, the `INSERT` may fail, or worse-- it may put the wrong data in each column.

I've found that when I `INSERT` a lot of columns, I find the queries easier to read if I can group them somehow.  If column names are long, I may put them on separate lines like so:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    MyTable_VeryLongName_Col1,
    MyTable_VeryLongName_Col4,
    MyTable_VeryLongName_Col8,
    -- etc.
)
SELECT
    Very_Long_Value_1,
    Very_Long_Value_4,
    Very_Long_Value_8,
    -- etc.
```

Or you can group 2 columns on a line, or put spaces on every 5, or comment every 10th line, etc.  Whatever makes it easier to read.

If you find including column names onerous when INSERTing a lot of rows, then try chaining the data together:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
VALUES ('val1A', 'val4A', 'val8A'),
    ('val1B', 'val4B', 'val8B'),
    -- etc.
```

Or `UNION` them together:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
SELECT 'val1A', 'val4A', 'val8A'
UNION ALL 'val1B', 'val4B', 'val8B'
UNION ALL ... -- etc.
```

Or, SELECT them from another table:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
SELECT val1, va4, val8
FROM MyOtherTable
WHERE -- some condition is met
```

Comment: I currently use the chaining method, but the reason this is unwieldy is because many of the columns I have contain binary data and it can be hard to match up which 1 and which 0 goes with which column during code reviews

Comment: I understand.  We have similar issues in our code.  I edited my post with some of our strategies we've used to make wide queries like this more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
VALUES ('val1', 'val4', 'val8')
```

This statement will add values to the columns mentioned in your `INSERT INTO` statement, you can write the above query in the following formats it will not make any difference .

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col8, col1, col4)
VALUES ('val8', 'val1', 'val4')
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col4, col8, col1)
VALUES ('val4', 'val8', 'val1')
```

to Add multiple rows at a time you can pass multiple rows at a time in you values clause something like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col4, col8, col1)
VALUES ('val4', 'val8', 'val1'),
       ('val4', 'val8', 'val1'),
       ('val4', 'val8', 'val1'),
       ('val4', 'val8', 'val1')
```

> The order of the values should match the order of the columns
>   mentioned in your INSERT INTO statement.

All above statement will have the same result.

keeping one thing in mind once you have mentioned a column you must provide a value for it

like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
VALUES ('val1', null, 'val8')
```

but you cannot do something like this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col4, col8)
VALUES ('val1', 'val8')
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do specifically what you want. The closest thing you can do is to use the column creation order to avoid use the columns names on the insert command. As this:

If you have a table like

```
tableA ( id, name, phone )
```

You can insert values on it using

```
insert into tableA values ( 1, 'Name', '555-9999' );
```

But be carefull, you have to follow the exact order on the fields of your table, otherwise you can have an error and worst, put wrong data in wrong fields.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cannot do it, the only other alternative for you would be insert from select

insert into MyTable 
select  'val1' as col1,  'val4' as col4,  'val8' as col8 --if any extra columns then just do "null as col10"

assuming the order is same in table